# Java File Output: Number formatting error for a card deck with number of cards only known at runtime

Tags: java

I made a successful card shuffling program which takes the number of cards of the deck as a user input at runtime, and prints each card on a separate line in the output text file.

I wanted to make an improvement to where If the deck was between 10 and 99 cards, the file would output the lines containing the numbers 1 through 9 as 01 through 09 instead.

I tried reading https://javadevnotes.com/java-integer-to-fixed-length-string and adapted it to my program. It compiled successfully on Jgrasp IDE but at runtime after entering the number of cards in the deck then the output filename, the program terminated with illegal format conversion exception on the line:

```
currentCard= String.format("%0"+ deckLimit.length() + "d", String.valueOf(tempValue));
```

How can I fix so this does not happen?

Relevent Variables:

```
String currentCard;
int tempValue;
int deckSize;
String deckLimit;
deckSize = read.nextInt();
deckLimit = String.valueOf(deckSize);
```

Problem line:

```
currentCard= String.format("%0"+ deckLimit.length() + "d", String.valueOf(tempValue));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a `%d` format specifier, but the value you're trying to format with it, `String.valueOf(tempValue)`, is a `String`.  If `tempValue` is the number you want formatted, then

```
 currentCard= String.format("%0"+ deckLimit.length() + "d", tempValue);
```

is the code you want.